# SQL group by row type, with type name in preceding row

Tags: sql, csv, group-by, ado, rowtype

I have a table that is formatted in the following way

```
| RowType  | Name      | Money Owned   | Creditor   |
-----------------------------------------------------
| family   | surname1  | 100           |            |
| person   | person1   | 20            | creditorA  |    
| person   | person2   | 30            | creditorA  |  
| person   | person2   | 10            | creditorB  | 
| person   | person2   | 20            | creditorC  | 
| person   | person3   | 20            | creditorB  |
| family   | surname2  | 80            |            | 
| person   | person4   | 30            | creditorA  | 
...
```

I am trying to get, for each family, the money they own to each creditor. The rows of type family contain in [Money Owned] the sum of the debts of their components. The "person" rows between two "family" rows contain the component of the preceding "family" row. The result I would like is

```
| Family   | Creditor    | Money Owned  |
-----------------------------------------
| surname1 | creditorA   | 50           |            
| surname1 | creditorB   | 30           |     
| surname1 | creditorC   | 20           |    
| surname2 | creditorC   | 30           |
```

That is I am trying to get sum of money owned, groupped by family and creditor. However, I do not have in each row the family name, and the only way I have to know the family name of a person is looking at which is the last preceding row that was of type family.

Reading answers to similar problems, I was thinking about building a temporary table where for each family I store the starting a finishing row somehow, and then in some way use this to accomplish the task. 
However, I would not know how to use ROW_NUMBER() since I cannot ORDER the data in a meaningful way.

Data is read from a csv through an ADO object (this will be performed inside a VBA script). 
I cannot add new columns to the table. I would prefer to avoid making copies of this file since it is huge. The table is what it is, and I cannot change its format.

Can you suggest an efficient way to accomplish the task?

Thanks

Comment: what rdbms ????

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of one row being "between" (or "before" or "after") other rows.  You need a separate column to specify the ordering.

Comment: I am in excel, using Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library (I don't have the version now, since I am not in the office), to create and ADO object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532(v=vs.85).aspx) and run a query on a csv file. The ordering I would like is the one of the csv file

Comment: Do really ADO allow to run SQL query on CSV file in excel? I may be wrong but ADO is  IMHO interface to database backend not engine itself